# Finding the limit of given expression in infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How should we find out the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2 \times 4 \times 6 \times \cdots \times 2n}{1 \times 4 \times 7 \times \cdots \times (3n - 2)}$$

I’ve tried using theorems that assist in calculating limits having an element of $\frac{i}{n}$ in them, but haven’t concluded any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be
$$
a_n  = \frac{{2 \cdot 4 \cdots \left( {2n} \right)}}
{{1 \cdot 4 \cdots \left( {3n - 2} \right)}}
$$
then you have that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \frac{{a_{n + 1} }}
{{a_n }} = \frac{{2 \cdot 4 \cdots \left( {2n} \right)\left( {2n + 2} \right)}}
{{1 \cdot 4 \cdots \left( {3n - 2} \right)\left( {3n + 1} \right)}} \cdot \frac{{1 \cdot 4 \cdots \left( {3n - 2} \right)}}
{{2 \cdot 4 \cdots \left( {2n} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\left( {2n + 2} \right)}}
{{\left( {3n + 1} \right)}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
and
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{a_{n + 1} }}
{{a_n }} = \frac{2}
{3}
$$
This means that
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ + \infty } {a_n } 
$$
by ratio test and therefore
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } a_n  = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You have
$$
\frac{2 \times 4 \times 6 \times \cdots \times 2n}
     {1 \times 4 \times 7 \times \cdots \times (3n - 2)}
 = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{3k-2}
$$
and the limit of the terms converges to $2/3$. What happens when you multiply numbers near $2/3$ by each other an infinite amount of times?